# How to call "Save Image As..." feature in Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Chrome extension library has knifty feature to call download method...however such callback doesn't enable us to script for the behavior when we right click an image - in fact it won't activate when right click on an image (would if it is a link).

What is Chrome's extension command that allows us to call for downloading an image? Thanks.

Comment: Are you having difficulty with the right click portion (a context menu)?  Or with getting the image to download after the click?

Comment: Right click (a context menu) - and perhaps I will have trouble getting image to download as well, lol - haven't gotten to that point yet.

Comment: Okay I think I misunderstood your question. I want to be able to remember the recent location when downloading like the behavior of Save Image As...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same question as you, but I have an alternative to do this: use `chrome.downloads.download` api.

Try to obtain the url of the image, and pass the url to the background script, which is the only location authorizing chrome.downloads api.

A sample use for this api is:

```
var name = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
chrome.downloads.download({url:url,filename:name,saveAs:false},function(res_id){
    if(typeof res_id === "undefined") // when failing to start the download
    {
        /*err handling*/
    }
    else
    {
        /*your further task*/
    }
});
```

Note that:

- The download location is the same as user's chrome setting.
- ***filename*** may contain the path and folder name before the file name, indicating sub-folder of the download location.
- It downloads auto without any popup windows to turn ***saveAs*** off;

Here's spec for more: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/downloads

Finally, I think it's just an alternative. I still want to know a perfect answer to the question, like what I also asked here:
[Does chrome extension api support downloads directly from browsing cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691443/does-chrome-extension-api-support-downloads-directly-from-browsing-cache)

Comment: Thanks Eric! This is the method I am using currently as well (similar). I too want the more "native" solution.

Comment: The reason being I want to bring up the download conversation window and save as a different name.

Comment: Okay, I figured out something. Here is my source code:

https://github.com/aeroxy/save_image

Comment: link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22691443/does-chrome-extension-api-support-downloads-directly-from-browsing-cache

Comment: `chrome.downloads` is undefined for me, missing any pre-requisite